# (J)Ruby - Is killing a thread okay?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, jruby

In Java, it's not okay to stop threads. So, I'm wondering whether this (Thread.exit) is okay in Ruby?

(FWIW, I'm using JRuby flavour of Ruby)

Comment: That's a very interesting question. In JRuby I'd assume that it's not ok for the same reasons as in Java. But perhaps it's ok for Ruby. In that case on the other hand the JRuby developers might have done some workarounds...

Answer (score 3):

In general, forcibly stopping *or* killing threads is always contraindicated, because you can't guarantee clean release of resources and locks that thread holds. So Nick is right, a variable indicating it's time for the thread to shut *itself* down is generally better.

For your case, however, there's probably no other option than to forcibly kill the thread. The safest route would be to Thread#raise something in the thread to allow normal exception-handling and ensure blocks to clean up resources. But of course that can be rescued by the user. However, JRuby *should* also run ensure blocks in response to an unrescuable Thread#kill. In either case, you can't guarantee that you're not interrupting an ensure block in progress, but for your case perhaps that's an acceptable risk.

Comment: Yes - a good idea to use exceptions if variables are not an option!

Comment: _The safest route would be to Thread#raise something in the thread to allow normal exception-handling and ensure blocks to clean up resources._ I'm actually worried about users writing infinite loops just for "fun". Also, is there a way to Thread#raise outside that thread?

Comment: "I'm actually worried about users writing infinite loops" - that's another question ;)

Comment: @RubyDosa: Why not solve the halting problem? :P (This is a joke - you can't actually solve the halting problem)

Comment: @Nick, Andrew: That's the main motive behind this question :(

Comment: @RubyDosa A solution may be to implement a notification system where if you detect processes have been running for an abnormal amount of time and aren't responding to Thread#raise you receive an email or SMS. You could then monitor and end the runaway thread manually.

Comment: @Nick: _then monitor and end the runaway thread manually._ Correct me if I'm wrong, if it's possible to do this manually, then there's a way to do this automatically too, right?

Comment: @RubyDosa It's not that there isn't a way to do it automatically, you could just call thread.stop(). The problem is that ending a thread in this way could cause problems with resources (etc..), so it's best someone is on standby when this happens. Think about when this happens on Windows, you get prompted a program isn't responding and get the option to force quit. It's not an easy problem to solve I know!

Answer (score 0):

I have no knowledge at all of Ruby - but I would still think it is probably safer to have a variable or flag to indicate when you would like the thread to end. You can then safely finish writing to memory and close resources that may have been opened.

N

Comment: Yes, that's always a good idea. But in my case, I run arbitrary code (user code, not under my control) in separate threads. So, I'm unable to use normal ways of gracefully stopping a thread.

Comment: Why run arbitrary user code in threads at all? Doing so potentially allows a thread to wreak havoc on the entire Ruby VM, affecting other threads. You'd be a lot safer running arbitrary user code in separate processes, for safety--and killing processes is eminently doable and supported.